# Aggregate an axis in data.frame in R

Tags: r, aggregation

Consider the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(sex     = c("MALE","FEMALE","MALE","FEMALE"),
                 time    = c("2018","2018","2019","2019"),
                 country = c("USA","USA","USA","USA"),
                 value   = c(10,10,10,10))
```

How do I aggregate the "sex" axis, so I get the following data:

```
    TIME    Country   Value
1   2018    USA       20
2   2019    USA       20
```

How do I do that in R (I know that it is probably a simple question)?

Comment: is this really the result you expect?

Comment: Sorry. Of course not. It is changed now. :-)

Comment: Try `aggregate` like :`aggregate(value ~ time + country, df, sum)`

Comment: This is a grouped sum, grouping by time and country - see the FAQ for several methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, the following does what you requested:

```
df %>% group_by(time, country)%>% summarize(sumval = sum(value))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   time [2]
  time  country sumval
  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
1 2018  USA         20
2 2019  USA         20
```